# Compiler error : No Architecture to Compile for(ARCH = i386 ValidArch : Armv6 Armv7)

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4, ios-simulator, xcode4.5

When am trying to build a project on Xcode version 4.0.1 it gives an compiler error.

```
   [BEROR]No architectures to compile for (ARCHS=i386, VALID_ARCHS=armv6 armv7)
```

So, I have followed the following procedure to make the project run

```
    1. Add i386 to valid archs
    2. Set Architecture as standard (armv6,armv7) 
    3. Set Buil valid architecture only - NO
    4. Clean 
    5. Build
```

But, I have got the following error now

**Unable to resolve Interface Builder plug-in dependency for "example.xib". Xcode 4   is missing components necessary to load the following class: IBNSLayoutConstraint. Ensure that Xcode has been properly installed.**

Can anyone help me to understand the problem and resolve it?